# funcion palo de carta javascritp

Tags: javascript

Me pueden ayudar con este problema.

Queremos escribir una función paloDeTruco, que dado un palo, devuelva una lista de strings, una por cada carta de ese palo según las cartas del truco:

paloDeTruco("espadas")
["1 de espadas", "2 de espadas", "3 de espadas" ..., "12 de espadas"]

Tomá en cuenta que las cartas de truco incluyen todas las numeradas del 1 al 12, excepto por los 8s y los 9s.

Escribí la función paloDeTruco que reciba el tipo de palo por parametro y devuelva un array.

Yo hice esto:

```js
function paloDeTruco(palo){
    var paloCarta = [ ];
    for( i = 1; i <= 12; i++){
        if ( i !=8 && i != 9){
            paloCarta.push( [i]+ "de" + palo);
        }
    }
    return (paloCarta);
}
```

Pero me da este error:
    La función paloDeTruco('espadas') debería contener el '10 de espadas'
    La función paloDeTruco('basto') debería contener el '1 de basto'

Comment: Cambia tu condición de `&&` (and) a `||` (or). Y comenta el resultado.

Comment: Ya lo hice. Pero me sigue dando este error:La función paloDeTruco('espadas') debería contener el '10 de espadas' , La función paloDeTruco('basto') debería contener el '1 de basto'

Answer (score 3):

Son los espacio entre el número, la palabra `de` y el tipo de palo:

Sin espacios:

```
paloCarta.push( [i]+ "de" + palo); 

['1deespadas','2deespadas'... ]
```

Con espacios:

```
paloCarta.push( [i]+ " de " + palo); 

['1 de espadas','2 de espadas'... ]
```

Si el primer código corre en una prueba unitaria no va a pasar porque los string dentro del arreglo no coinciden.

Comment: Tiene razon, era solo el espacio. Pero que tonta!!